# Execute implicit cast at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

So I have a Generic class (it's mostly a container class) with implicit casting, like this:

```
public class Container<T>  
{  
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator T(Container<T> t)
        {
            return t.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Container<T>(T t)
        {
            return new Container<T>() { Value = t };
        }
}
```

So in runtime I would like to cast an instance of `Container<int>` to int using reflection but cannot seem to find a way, I've tried the "Cast" method invoking mentioned in a couple of places but I'm getting an `Specified cast is not valid.` exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So what do you know at compile time and what do you know at execution time? Could you give us the calling code?

Comment: Are you trying to "Cast" Container to int, or Container.Value?

Comment: Why don't you just call `Container.Value`?

Comment: I will not necessarily know that the instance of a generic variable has a 'Value' property, this was just a simplified example, essentially I want to (attempt to) cast the container variable to the type that it contains, e.g. cast `Tuple<int>` to `int`, assuming `Tuple<int>` actually has a implicit cast to it's contained type, or like my Container, cast a `Container<Customer>` to `Customer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's almost never a good reason to do this unless the type in question is internal to an assembly that you cannot modify.

But if it came to that, I would personally prefer the much cleaner-looking `dynamic` solution (as mentioned by jbtule) to reflection.

But since you asked for a solution with reflection (perhaps you are on .NET 3.5 or earlier?), you can do:

```
object obj = new Container<int>();

var type = obj.GetType();
var conversionMethod = type.GetMethod("op_Implicit", new[] { type });
int value = (int)conversionMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the dlr, accessible by the open source [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) in nuget, you can dynamically [call an implicit or explicit cast](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding).

```
int intInstance =Impromptu.InvokeConvert(containerInstance, typeof(int));
```

although this example is rather trival and can be accomplished via

```
int intInstance = (dynamic) containerInstnace;
```

as well. but if you don't know `int` at compile time Impromptu is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Writing implicit operators allow you to make the casts *implicitly*. In other words, this is perfectly legal:

```
int i = new Container<int>() { Value = 2 };
if (i == 2) 
{
    // This will be executed
}
```

If you only have a `Container<object>` then that won't work, but in that case your code should probably be refactored anyway, since you're essentially ignoring the generic parameter you have.